# Calling macroexpand at runtime

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp

Is it possible to expand a macro at run time in a compiled lisp executable? I would expect it to be impossible as macro expansion can only happen pre-compilation yet when i call macroexpand in compiled code i get output.

Comment: The same reason you can call `EVAL` at run time.

Comment: Macros are expanded automatically during compilation and evaluation, but you can still expand them explicitly in code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A macro is a function that's normally called automatically during compilation or evaluation, and whose return value is then compiled or evaluated in place of the original expression.

But since it's just a function, there's nothing preventing it from being called explicitly during run time as well, and that's what `MACROEXPAND` and `MACROEXPAND-1` do.

It's roughly equivalent to:

```
(defun macroexpand-1 (form &optional env)
  (if (and (listp form) (car form)) ;; list expression
      (let ((macfun (macro-function (car form)))
        (if macfun
            (funcall macfun form env)
            form))
      form))
```

(Note that this definition doesn't handle symbol macros or use `*MACROEXPAND-HOOK*`, to keep it simple.)

It's possible to use `EVAL-WHEN` when defining the macro to make the macro definition only available in the compilation environment. If you do that, trying to expand at run time will fail.

Answer (score 4):

In Lisp, the terms "run time" and "compile time" are situations in which a particular piece of code is being processed, not absolutes like in some static languages. If we evaluate `(compile nil '(lambda ()))`, this is the `compile` function's run-time, but the `lambda` form's compile time: both times are happening at the same time.

The entire language is available in all situations. When you build a self-contained executable, that image contains not only support for expanding macros, but for compiling code. Your Lisp application can call `compile-file` to compile Lisp source to object form, and `load` to load the resulting object code.

The process of removing garbage, and unused functionality from a Lisp application image to make it smaller is called ["tree shaking"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_shaking). If you don't want the compiler or macro expander in your application, find out whether/how they can be removed with your implementation's tree shaking support.